# Destructure ES6 in React props

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to destructure my props two levels down. I know you can do it like this:

```
const MyComponent = ({ aPropOneLevelDown: { anotherPropButTwoLevelsDown } }) => { ... }
```

I know this will work, but the issue is when *aPropOneLevelDown* is not defined yet. Then I get the error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'anotherPropButTwoLevelsDown' of undefined

What can I do to keep the advantage of destructuring?

Comment: assign `defaultProps`  to the component https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-default-props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [default props](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-default-props)

Like this

```
const MyComponent = ({aPropOneLevelDown: { anotherPropButTwoLevelsDown } = {}}) => {}
```

Or this

```
const MyComponent = ({aPropOneLevelDown: { anotherPropButTwoLevelsDown }}) => {}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    aPropOneLevelDown: {}
}
```